# PHP Function To Grab First Letter, Or Return # If It's a Number

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a php function that will grab the first letter from a long string ("ZT-FUL-ULT-10SF-S" would return "Z").

Some of the strings start with numbers, and for those, the function needs to return "#".

```
function returnFirst($rsrnum)  {
    substr("$rsrnum", 0, 1); {
        echo "$rsrnum";
    } 
}
```

That's as far as I've gotten.  How would I differentiate between numbers, and if it is a number, return #?

Thanks!

Edit: Seems to be working like a champ with:

`function returnFirst($rsrnum)  {
      $char = substr($rsrnum, 0, 1);
         return ctype_alpha($char) ? $char : "#";
}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ctype_alpha`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) to check if the first character is a letter and return accordingly:

```
$char = substr($rsrnum, 0, 1);
return ctype_alpha($char) ? $char : "#";
```

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to check `ctype_digit` as well.  Checking both allows you to handle the 3rd option: an invalid first character (non alpha-numeric).

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Possibly, but it depends on the caller. If they are not explicitly coded to recognize a third option ("unexpected") there's not much point in returning a third value.

Answer (score 0):

A little delayed. but I think this might do the trick just fine!

```
function CheckFirst($String,$CharToCheck = 1){
    if ($CharToCheck < 1){
        return false;
    }
    $First_Char = $String{$CharToCheck - 1}; // Seek first Letter of Entered String

    if (ctype_alpha($First_Char) === true){
        // If the first Letter is in the aplhabet (A-Z/a-z)
        return "First Character Is A String";
    }elseif (ctype_digit($First_Char) === true){
        // If The first Letter is a digit (0-9)
        return "First Character Is A Digit";
    }
}
```

I've left the function to return a string, so it's clear what will be returned upon pushing a string to the function. Suit the returns to your requirements

*Edited the function to perform a better role within the script.  It can now be called to check more than the first character of a string. Defaulting to the first*